# About PHP/Java Bridge Invoke Java method with Object parameter

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I had success to run Php/Java bridge project and test.php
but i got a problem.
i would like to invoke a Java method with Java Object parameter
**Java Source:**

```
public class OtherClass {
    public BaseBean funBean(BaseBean param){
        param.setName("Bean Name");
        return param;
    }
}

public class BaseBean {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String name;

}
```

**PHP Script:**
I would like to it can run like that,it can't.

```
<?php
require_once("java/Java.inc");
//require_once("java/java_helper.php");

class BaseBean{
    public $name;
}
$eh = new java("com.anima.service.OtherClass");
$cla = new BaseBean();
$cla->name = "nameTest";
$eh->funBean($cla);
?>
```

Or there are some solution can help me to implement this idea.
I want to invoke java method with php object.

Can you please anyone help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should create BaseBean as a "java instance" as well:

```
$cla = new java("com.anima.service.BaseBean");
```

Or alternatively you can try out with java_closure but I think in this case you have to change the expected type in your java method like this:

```
public Object funBean(Object param){ ... }
$cla = new BaseBean();
$cla->name = "nameTest";
$jObjCla = java_closure($cla);
$eh->funBean($jObjCla);
```

I've found in [PHP/Java bridge documentation](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/docs/php-api/__filesource/fsource_java__JavaProxy.inc.html#a578) that java_closure method has got a third parameter what is an array of Java interfaces should be implemented by the created wrapped object:

```
java_closure(new Listener(), null, array(new Java("java.awt.event.ActionListener")));
```

**Java source:**

```
public interface IBaseBean {
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
}

public class OtherClass {
    public IBaseBean funBean(IBaseBean param){
        param.setName("Bean Name");
        return param;
    }
}

public class BaseBean implements IBaseBean {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String name;
}
```

**PHP script:**

```
<?php
require_once("java/Java.inc");

class BaseBean{
    public $name;
}
$eh = new java("com.anima.service.OtherClass");
$cla = new BaseBean();
$cla->name = "nameTest";
$jObjCla = java_closure($cla, null, array(new Java("com.anima.service.IBaseBean")));
$eh->funBean($jObjCla );
?>
```

Comment: thanks to answer,but it got a error
java call stack:
Feb 11 19:52:15 JavaBridge ERROR: An exception occured: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
php call stack:
Warning: Unchecked exception detected: [[o:Response$UndeclaredThrowableErrorMarker]:"FATAL: Undeclared java.lang.RuntimeException detected. java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[o:OtherClass]]->funBean((o:BaseBean)[o:$Proxy1]). Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch VM:

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot try it out now because I don't have an environment here but have you changed the funBean method as well? (to expect the interface instead of the class)

Comment: so, is it working now? or shall I check it when I arrive home?

Comment: yes,it work,Thanks a lot:) but php script should implements getter&setter just like Java interface